# How to redirect a website from the server on an Ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, http

Is it possible to redirect a web site from the server on an ajax request?

Eg.

1. The website (www.myapp.com) makes an ajax request to the server.
2. The server redirects to the same URL with a hash eg. www.myapp.com#page=main.
3. Website is redirected to www.myapp.com#page=main.

I need to redirect it to the same url but with a hash.

Using window.location.href = http://www.myapp.com#page=main won't work since it will just update the location with the hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aeah, it is. You can use meta or javascript redirect. Just append following code into an ajax reponse & make sure that reponse is placed into actual page

```
 <script>document.location.href='newpage.php'</script>
```

or to refresh, return

```
 <script>document.location.reload(1);</script>
```

Comment: Sorry for not being explicit. Please read my updated question. I need to redirect it to the same url with a hash.

Comment: @ajsie: "redirect" ? Why do you want to redirect? hmm, just redirect to the page with hash and then refresh()

Comment: Stupid me: I could just use location.reload(true). Thanks!

Comment: @ajsie: oh reload(), not refresh, sorry

Answer (score 2):

No.
An AJAX request just returns data to the client; the browser does not act on it at all.

Instead, you need to make the server tell your client code to do a redirect in its response, then write client code to check whether the server asked it to redirect and navigate to the new location.